# AVR: Usage of Force Output Compare bits

Tags: microcontroller, avr

Currently I'm dealing with Tiny2313 for my project. Timer runs in CTC (WGM12) mode so OCR1A is used to set TOP of the timer. I want to use OCR1B to generate output signal.

In documentation is mentioned this: "The FOC1A/FOC1B bits are only active when the WGM13:0 bits specifies a non-PWM mode." Is usage of that bits in non-PWM mode mandatory? 
What is true purpose of FOC1A/FOC1B bits?

Comment: The purpose is right what it says on the package: to force a match with the appropriate register regardless of its actual value.

Comment: Usage is not mandatory, they are just there for you to trigger the Output Compare at an arbitrary moment.

Comment: So.. basically, it is used to output compare asynchronously. Out of curiosity - Do you know some application where Force Output Compare can be useful?